# How to find an index inside a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find JOKER1 and swap it with the card that follows it (inside a circular deck of cards) but I just can't seem to find the correct code. 
If I have a code as

```
def move_joker_1(i):
    i[i.index(27)], i[i.index(27) + 1] = i[i.index(27) + 1], i[i.index(27)]
    print(i)
```

I always get `move_joker_1()` takes 1 positional argument but `x` (a number) were given.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so it will be easier to help you. Also try to formulate a clear question.

Comment: What are you expecting `i.index(27)` to be? Is `27` a value that represents "JOKER1" in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Pass in the list of cards as *one* argument:

```
move_joker_1(cards)
```

Do **not** use the `*splat` syntax; `move_joker_1(*cards)` would apply *each card* as a separate argument.

You may want to call `i.index(27)` just once, and take into account it could be at the *end* of the list:

```
def move_joker_1(i):
    joker_pos = i.index(27)
    swap_with = joker_pos + 1
    if swap_with == len(i):
        swap_with = 0
    i[joker_pos], i[swap_with] = i[swap_with], i[joker_pos]
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
i = ["KING1", "JACK2", "JOKER1", "QUEEN4"]
def move_joker_1(i):
    n = i.index("JOKER1")
    joker = i[n]
    i[n] = i[n+1]
    i[n+1] = joker

move_joker_1(i)
print i
```